# Setting limit on array and delete values past that limit

Tags: php, session

I got an element that shows the last viewed products by a customer. It stores the product ids in a session and uses those ids in a query to get all the products. The problem is, there is a limit of 3 products, I can add `LIMIT 0,3` in the query but this doesn't limit the amount of ids stored in the session.

An example of what I got:

On the product page:

```
$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = $productcr[0]['id'];
```

On the catalog page:

```
if($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] != ''){
    $prods  = implode(",", $_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);
}
$laatst  = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE id IN ($prods) and state = 1 ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 0,3";
```

The query then looks like this when echoed:

```
SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE id IN (7,6,5,7,8,5) and state = 1 ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

How can I make sure only 3 ids are in the session at all times?

For example when the session contains 3,2,1 and a customer views product 4 the session should contain 4,3,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last three ids only in `$prods` then use `array_slice()` to achieve that check herehttp://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php
 Try like this

```
if($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] != ''){
  $prods  = implode(",", array_slice($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'],-3));
}
$laatst  = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE id IN ($prods) and state = 1 ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 0,3";
```

To remove **duplicate product ids** use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
Do like this

```
 if($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] != ''){
      $result = array_unique($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);
      $prods  = implode(",", array_slice($result,-3));
    }
    $laatst  = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE id IN ($prods) and state = 1 ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 0,3";
```

**Edit2:-**

```
if($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] != ''){
    $result = array_unique(array_reverse($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']));
    $result=array_reverse($result);
    $prods  = implode(",", array_slice($result,-3));
}
```

Comment: This works but when a user views a product 3 times when there are already 2 products in the session there will be the same product 3 times and so in the list it will only show 1 product. Is it easy to check if a number exists?

Comment: Okay i just update my answer for same product just use that it will work for you.

Comment: Almost there but when I watch three products, and then a 4th one it doesn't change anymore. An old value is not deleted and stays in the array, so when I watch 3 products, then a 4th one that was already watched before the 3 that are shown, it will not be added.

Comment: This is the array (id 7 was watched first) Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 [2] => 5 [4] => 6 ) and this is shown in the query (8,5,6) even when 7 was watched later, because its already in the array it doesn't add it anymore. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

A function that adds to an array an element if it doesn't already exist.

Let's suppose the below :

- `$mArray` is your `$_SESSION['laatstbekeken']`
- `$currentProduct` is your `$productcr[0]['id']`

And that you have already 3 product id's inside the `$mArray(1,2,3)`. The current product you are viewing is `4` so it must be added to the `array`.

```
$mArray = [3,2,1];

$currentProduct = 4;


echo "<pre>Before : <br/>";
print_r($mArray);

echo "<br/>After : <br/>";
$mArray = addProductToArray($currentProduct, $mArray);

print_r($mArray);




function addProductToArray($mCurrentProduct, $mArray){

    if(sizeof($mArray) < 3){

        if(!in_array($mCurrentProduct, $mArray)){
            $mArray[] = $mCurrentProduct;
        }

    }
    else{

        if(!in_array($mCurrentProduct, $mArray)){
            array_pop($mArray);
            array_unshift($mArray, $mCurrentProduct);
        }
    }

    return $mArray;



}
```

Output :

```
Before : 
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)

After : 
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below:

On the product page:

```
if(count($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']) < 3 )
    $_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = $productcr[0]['id'];
else{
    array_pop($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);
    $_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = $productcr[0]['id'];
}
print_r($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);
```

On the catalog page:

```
if($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] != '' && count($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']) == 3 ){
    echo $prods  = implode(",", $_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After insert the new product, slice the array like this:
`$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] = array_slice($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'], -3, 3);`

This sample helps to view the result:

```
<?php

$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = 12;
$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = 13;
$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = 14;

var_dump($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);

$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = 15;
$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = 16;

var_dump($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);

$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] = array_slice($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'], -3, 3);

var_dump($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);

$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = 17;
$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = 18;

$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] = array_slice($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'], -3, 3);

var_dump($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);
```

The output will be:

```
/sess.php:7:
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(12)
  [1] =>
  int(13)
  [2] =>
  int(14)
}
/sess.php:12:
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  int(12)
  [1] =>
  int(13)
  [2] =>
  int(14)
  [3] =>
  int(15)
  [4] =>
  int(16)
}
/sess.php:16:
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(14)
  [1] =>
  int(15)
  [2] =>
  int(16)
}
/sess.php:23:
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(16)
  [1] =>
  int(17)
  [2] =>
  int(18)
}
```